# Находится ли выбранная дата в определённом диапазоне

Tags: c#

Мне нужно узнать находится ли выбранная дата в определённом диапазоне дат(таких диапазонов 12). Можно ли это как-то сделать не создавая 25 переменных?

Само задание: создайте проект, позволяющий по дате рождения определить знак зодиака и увидеть картинку этого знака (использовать перечисление).

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример с числами:

```cs
int[][] ranges = new int[][] {
    new int[] {1, 5},
    new int[] {6, 10},
    new int[] {11, 15},
    new int[] {16, 20},
    new int[] {21, 25},
    new int[] {26, 30},
    new int[] {31, 35}
};

int number = 17;

if (number < ranges[0][0] || number > ranges[ranges.GetLength (0) - 1][1])
    System.Console.WriteLine ("Неверное число.");
else 
    foreach (var range in ranges)
        if (number >= range[0] && number <= range[1]) {
            System.Console.WriteLine ($"Число {number} находится в диапазоне [{range[0]};{range[1]}].");
            break;
        }

System.Console.ReadKey ();
```

Пример результата работы программы с числом 17:

> Число 17 находится в диапазоне [16;20].

Таким образом можно проверять и даты. К примеру, есть диапазоны дней в году для знаков зодиака. Переводим дату в день года (05.01 в 5, к примеру) и проверяем таким кодом на соответствие какому-либо диапазону.

Comment: Ваш ответ дает подсказку, но не отвечает на вопрос. Объяните автору, что именно он должен понять из примера.

Comment: Добавил пояснение.

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю весьма необычное решение для такой задачи.

Возьмем входные данные и обьявим все нужные данные для фильтрации:

```
var monthToSearch = 01;
var dateToSearch = 23;
string zodiakName; //result

var startDates = ["01.22","02.19","03.21"];// дальше заполнишь сам
var zodiaks = new Dictionary<int, String>() {
   { 1, "Водолей" }, 
   { 2, "Рыбы" }, 
   { 3, "Овен" } 
   // дальше заполнишь сам
};
```

Обрати внимание что номер знака зодиака в половине случаев соответствует номеру из ключа дикшнари и номеру месяца который мы ищем.

И того весь наш поиск сводится к:

```
var startDate = startDates[ monthToSearch - 1];
startDay = startDate.split(".")[2];// здесь нужно привести к Int - не помню как єто делается, сейчас работаю с другим языком

zodiakName = (dateToSearch > startDay) ? zodiaks[monthToSearch] : monthToSearch[monthToSearch - 1]
```

Единственное что этот код не учитывает - это поиск Козерога. То есть если мы будем искать 1 месяц 21 число оно выдаст ошибку). Исправление этого поведения на тебе будет :) Это + 1 строка

Код не проверял а просто писал из головы, потому могут быть мелкие синтаксические ошибки. Возможны и мелкие логические, но их тоже будет просто найти в 3х строках кода.

Так же желательно переназвать переменные, их имена у меня кривые, влом придумывать хорошие.

Что бы полностью соответствовать задаче нужно заменить название знака в дикшинари на картинку -- Но тестить лучше с названиями.

---

Прошу заметить что решение без переборов и циклов. Вероятнее всего это одно из самых оптимальных по скорости решений. Хотя в этой задаче это абсолютно бесполезно

И да, тебя могут спалить что писала не ты если покажешь этот код)